# Elements on view not working after rendering with ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have multiple html elements on the view that are loaded with the ajax call. These html elements depends on javascript files that i have included. It is working properly when loaded without ajax but when i load it with ajax it stops working.

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','form#hc',function(e){
    jQuery.ajax({
                    'url' : baseUrl+'manage-function',
                    'dataType': 'json',
                    'type' : 'post',
                    'data': {formData : formData},
                    success:function(response){
                        jQuery('.function_div').html(response.html);
                    } 
                });
});
```

Comment: In the success callback, whats the result of `console.log(jQuery('.function_div').length)`?

Comment: @fonini: If i place javascript depended code in success function then it starts working. But it is too large code i do not want to repeat.

Comment: Don't. just make sure it is delegated the same way you already did with your submit above

Comment: @mplungjan: Can u please provide me some link.

Comment: Look at the dupe! `$('.function_div').on("click","someselectorfromresponse",function() {})`

Comment: @mplungjan: html is loading but in that html there is timepicker that is initialised in some other script that was loaded on page load and working on page load but after rendering that view with ajax timepicker does not load

Comment: You cannot load HTML without re-initialising things like time pickers